# Problem communicating with one machine in my domain

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, ping

Context:

- 3 HyperV guest images (DC, SQL, MOSS)
- 1 internal network
- 1 domain (PJM.COM)
- DC:  192.168.0.192
- SQL: 192.168.0.153
- MOSS:192.168.0.160

I am having communication problems from/to the MOSS machine from the other two.  I removed the MOSS machine from the domain and cannot rejoin.

When I ping the MOSS machine from DC, I get the following response:

```
Pinging MOSS [192.168.0.152]
Reply from 192.168.0.192 Destination host unreachable (4 times)
```

When I ping the MOSS machine from SQL, I get the following response:

```
Pinging MOSS [192.168.0.152]
Reply from 192.168.0.153 Destination host unreachable (4 times)
```

From the MOSS machine, I can ping the server names, however I cannot ping the FQDN.

When I ping from the DC and SQL machines, I get IPv4 addresses.
When I ping from the MOSS machine, I get IPv6 addresses.

I'm a developer and don't know what steps to take to resolve this issue.  Please help!?

Answer (score 0):

From what you've displayed there, `moss` is resolving to `192.168.0.152`, however in your specs at the top of the question you've mentioned that `moss` is running on `192.168.0.160`. This means that your DNS for `moss` is incorrect.

Jump onto your DC and fire up the DNS management console (Admin Tools > DNS). In the Forward Lookup Zone for `pjm.com` find the record for `moss` and make sure its IP address is correct.

If you want to force `ping` to use IPv4 or IPv6, suffix the command with `-4` or `-6` (whichever is appropriate)

Comment: The entry was not correct.  However, something else is wrong here.  

I can ping the domain control machine (DC) from the MOSS machine.  It will only return back a ipv6.  If I specify -4, it does not find anything.  

In addition, I cannot ping the MOSS machine (via IP or name) from the DC.  In addition, I cannot join the domain from the MOSS machine.

Comment: In that case, I would also check to see that the DNS server is set correctly on the MOSS machine. If it is not, this would also explain why the IP address was not updated automatically when the machine registered itself against the DNS.

Comment: The DNS server is pointing to 192.168.0.192 (the DC).  This is the same as the SQL machine. I comared all the IP settings to the SQL machine and they were all set the same.  Could this be an issue with the netowrk card MAC address for this specific VM?  I can create new VM's and joing them to this domain.

Comment: Hmm, I doubt it's a VM issue. I've honestly no idea from this stage onwards. Is IPv4 still enabled on the MOSS machine?